# Python inspection: get only the methods defined in child class

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, inspect

I have the following class structure

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        inspect.getmembers(module, predicate=inspect.ismethod)

# c.py    
class C(A):
    def myfunc(self):
        pass
```

I want to get the list of functions defined in C in the `__init__` of my class B. The problem with my inspect line is that it returns every method defined by A along with C since C inherits from A. Is there a pythonic way to exclusively get the methods directly defined in C. So only get `myfunc` when that line is run

Comment: What's `module`?

Comment: Just to let you know, comments in Python are made using `#` not `//`.

Comment: @ChristianDean Whoopsie!